# How to remove row if it has a NA value in one certain column

Tags: r, na

My data called "dat":

```
A   B   C
NA  2   NA
1   2   3
1   NA  3
1   2   3
```

I want to be all rows to be removed if it has an NA in column B:

```
A   B   C
NA  2   NA
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

`na.omit(dat)` removes all rows with an `NA` not just the ones where the NA is in column B.

Also I'd like to know how to this for NA value in two columns.

I appreciate all advice!

Comment: Try with `is.na` i.e. `dat[!is.na(dat$B),]` or `subset(dat, !is.na(B))` or `library(dplyr);dat %>% filter(!is.na(B))` or `data.table` `setDT(dat)[!is.na(B)]`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `is.na()`:

```
df[!is.na(df$B), ]
```

which gives you:

```
   A B  C
1 NA 2 NA
2  1 2  3
4  1 2  3
```

Comment: Why do you need the comma "," after "(df$B)" ?

Comment: when you subset a data.frame with square brackets, the element before the comma applies to rows, the element after the comma to columns. if you don't use the comma, R will assume you are selecting columns.

Comment: This answer provides a big speed improvement over the tidyverse option! Average speed of 200us (base) vs 1400ms (tidyverse)

Answer (score 26):

there is an elegant solution if you use the `tidyverse`!

it contains the library `tidyr` that provides the method `drop_na` which is very intuitive to read.

So you just do:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% drop_na("B")
```

OR

```
dat %>% drop_na(B)
```

if B is a column name

Comment: I'd add that this answer is useful if passing strings to functions which are intended to be used as column names.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
df<-data.frame(A=c(NA,1,1,1),B=c(2,2,NA,2),C=c(NA,3,3,3))
df<-df[-which(is.na(df$B)),]
df
   A B  C
1 NA 2 NA
2  1 2  3
4  1 2  3
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
dat <- dat[dat['B'].notnull()]
```